# Update rows that have the same values in two columns in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table have the same values in two columns. I would like to update only one row where in column `login` and `email` are the same value and `data modification` is earlier. So, in this example below it must update only one row with `ID = 2`. What SQL statement should I use?

```
ID | login   |email                |data modification
---|---------|---------------------|-----------------
1  | abc     |john@mail.com        |   2017-01-10
2  | abc     |john@mail.com        |   2017-02-14
3  | example |john123@hotmail.com  |   2017-02-17
```

Comment: Where is your query? Do you expect us to write it for you?

Comment: @Wim Ombelets I ask for the query, so I don't know what I may to put...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a cte to get the first records (based on `data modification`) for each `Login` and `Email` combination:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Login, Email ORDER BY [data modification]) as rn
    FROM <Table>
)

UPDATE t
SET <column> = <value>
FROM <Table> t
INNER JOIN CTE ON t.Id = CTE.Id
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you are working on version 2012 or higher, you can write it even shorter, using [`First_Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT FIRST_VALUE(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY Login, Email ORDER BY [data modification]) as FirstId
    FROM <Table>
)

UPDATE t
SET <column> = <value>
FROM <Table> t
INNER JOIN CTE ON t.Id = CTE.Id
```

Comment: i gave my +1 but the CTE is not really needed, you can make a nested query out of the window function query

Comment: @ThomasG That's correct, but once I've got used to working with CTEs, derived tables seems less readable to me.